# Usage of "illiteracy" in certain sentences

Tags: word-usage, sentence

How to use the "illiteracy" word in sentences when you want to mention your illiteracy related to some topics or areas? I'm a native Russian speaker, and when I write English text, I can make mistakes, and that mistakes make me to look illiterate. What words do I need to use to mention that I'm not illiterate as a whole but I can be illiterate when I use this exact language?

For example, I wanted to write something like "sorry for my illiteracy in English". Is it a correct sentence if I want to mention that when I use English, I can sometimes write sentences which can be considered illiterate?

I googled examples of "illiteracy" usage, but cannot find this exact usecase.

*(Will be glad to see any examples, including non-informal, including sentences which do not use the "illiteracy" word but which have close meaning.)*

P.S. Exact sentence I was trying to construct: "Kind people will never left me alone with my illiteracy in English." — is it a correct one?

Comment: "I don't speak idiomatic English" or "My English is not fluent" sound far more appropriate than "I'm illiterate", Ronin.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I also added exact sentence I was trying to construct and which forced me to ask this question. (see the "P.S." part).

Comment: I don't understand the use of 'kind' there. Hedging (marking with politeness elements) doesn't work this way. "Please excuse my less than fluent English" is perhaps what you want. // Note that 'will ...' requires the base form of the verb, 'will never leave me ...'.

Comment: [Illiterate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illiterate) means unable to read and write; it doesn't mean making mistakes, else we'd all be illiterate.

Comment: (Sorry for)/(Please excuse) my poor English. I’m still (learning)/(working on it).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, "kind = friendly, generous, and considerate". I'm trying to make a sentence, where I directly call them "kind people" but in the second part I mention that they will never miss a chance to show me my illiteracy, and it makes the "kind people" part of the sentence to be sarcastic. So, any "please excuse my [something]" will just destroy the joke.

Comment: @StuartF, can "illiterate" be used as a hyperbola? It's possible in Russian language, so I thought English allows to do the same.

Comment: Sarcasm is common in English, too:  So many have been kind enough to correct my every mistake in English. For that I am, well, thankful.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, exactly what I was searching for. Thank you so very much for the example!